# How can I restores Nautilus' old open with context menu?

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

On Ubuntu prior to 16.10 Nautilus provided the following open with context menu:

[image: Old open with]

Under Ubuntu 16.10 it now looks as follows:

[image: New open with]

**How can I restore the old open with context menu for quicker access to the applications?**

Comment: Would like to re-open this, just wondering whether anyone has an update as it relates to 17.10.  I honestly think the 'Open With' context menu is extremely useful in terms of productivity.

Comment: You should follow [bug 777132](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777132).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to enable the old **Open With** version in Nautilus 3.20. There's no possibility to do it by changing it in the Preferences, there is also no option to do it using the `dconf-editor` tool.

That is due to how Nautilus 3.20, as part of the GNOME 3.20 desktop environment was designed. As there is no plugin available in the repositories to add this feature, you'll have to use it 'as it is'.

Of course it might be possible to tune the software by changing the code ... but this might break some other things and the main functionality still exists, you just have to make a few clicks more.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Gnome >= 3.20, like Gnome 3.38 with Ubuntu 20.10, is to use [nautilus-open-with-menu](https://github.com/maoschanz/nautilus-open-with-menu) that bring a automatic list of applications to open-with.